# websocket will not connect from remote server

Tags: websocket, firewall

I have a web page to control a thermostat on a raspberry pi, and I'm running into difficulties when trying to get websockets to work from a remote client.  It seems to work fine when on LAN however.  I'm obviously missing something (and likely something basic), but I can't seem to figure out what it is.

The pi's local ip is `192.168.1.134`.   The web page (served from apache server) has the URL `http://192.168.1.134:8010/thermostat.html`.   The page starts up some javascript, which then tries to connect to the pi's main program using websockets via `ws://192.168.1.134:9000`.  (the server on the pi is running libwebsockets).   The websocket comes up, and it seems to work fine.   I then tried to connect via a remote client (a cell phone, where wifi was turned off) from `http:\\23.239.99.99:8010\thermostat.html`.   The html/js files load fine, but the web socket attempts to connect to uri `ws:\\23.239.99.99:9000`, and this fials.

As far as I can tell, the NAT seems to be configured properly:

```
name           ext     ext    protocol    int     int     ip addr     interface
               port    port               port    port
               start   end                start   end

Thermostat3     8010   8010   TCP        8010   8010    192.168.1.134   eth3.1  
Thermostat5     8000   8000   TCP/UDP    80     80      192.168.1.134   eth3.1  
Thermostat_ws   9000   9000   TCP/UDP    9000   9000    192.168.1.134   eth3.1
```

I checked, and the router does not have any firewalls set up, neither does my modem.   I didn't install a firewall on the pi (I checked, and there's no odd iptables rule).   Does anyone know what I'm missing?

**--- EDIT ---**

I'm still stuck on this.   I called my ISP and they assure me there are no firewalls on their servers.   Is there any way to tell if port 9000 is being blocked, and by who?

Comment: Two thoughts: Are you _sure_ that the ws connection uses the external i.p. ? (Like it's not hard-coded in your html and hasn't been updated?)  More usefully - It might be worth attempting to use port 443 as that's often 'more open' than others (but given 8010 is working, that might be a stretch).

Comment: Sorry, I've been away a couple of days, so slow getting back to this.  Those are both valid points.   The js code uses `ws_uri += "//" + window.location.host.replace(/\:.*$/, '') + ":9000";` as the uri, which I print out, and it shows up correctly.   I tried with 443, but it has same behavior (works from lan, not from wan...)

Comment: Having the same issue. When connecting to a websocket remotely, I receive "500 handshakefailed" error. Looking for solution 2nd week already, and noone suggest one.

Answer (score 2):

Bind your apache server to 0.0.0.0 address to make it accessible from remote machines

Comment: It's accessible from other machines (namely any computer connecting via LAN), but not from anything crossing the router.  Theoretically, the router should NAT the outside access so it looks like the request is coming to192.168.1.134, so apache shouldn't be able to see the difference...

Answer (score 1):

Try this tool to determine if the port is inaccessible (use the custom port): http://www.whatsmyip.org/port-scanner/

Everything else looks fine. As a sanity check I would try putting the ws port to 8010 to see if that works. I would also recommend using a tool like Advanced Web Client to isolate networking issues.

Answer (score 1):

This is interesting. I once had a similar problem. I set up a WebSocket (I was using a nodejs [ws](https://websockets.github.io/ws/)) and once I tried to access it from remote client I was not able to reach it with `ws://yourip:port` but instead I had to use `http://yourip:port`. I don't know if you have the same problem, mine was due to a proxy I was using.

I still have an advice for you how you might be able to solve your problem. I don't know how concerned you are about security but as far as I understood your idea you basically connect to your raspberry pi through a WebSocket and tell it to change the temperature.
 Back when did a similar project I found it rather hard to secure my WebSocket connection. I was basically sending a password plus command through the WebSocket to my server which then checks wether the password is correct. Otherwise everyone on the internet could heat your house. Not cool...
But therefore, I had to tunnel the connection through https to prevent a middleware attack.
I quickly threw the towel and decided to go with a completely different solution. Basically I set up a nodejs express server (can easily be configured with a self signed certificate to use https or used behind a nginx/apache https server) and authenticated with username and password. When someone made a POST request to /api/thermostats?id=0 with a temperature request, the server checks if the user is authenticated and then executes a terminal command from within node.
Maybe this idea also fits your demands.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am planning on doing going forward.  The web page will be served over https/wss,  A user will by default be able to view the status, but in order to change the temperature, the js app will have to send its credentials.   The credentials can generated doing password authentication, or they can be stored/loaded in a cookie on the device.